# Where I can find a summary of Ubuntu's current functionality on touch screen devices?

Tags: input-devices, touchscreen

Is there an Ubuntu site where I can find a summary of Ubuntu's current functionality on touch screen devices?

And, hopefully, a list of touch screen devices still in production that it will run on?

Answer (score 0):

Within my limited knowledge, I did little search about the information that you are looking for.

Found following links:

[What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)

[Detailed Review of Ubuntu Touch 14.04 with Mir display and Unity 8](http://www.noobslab.com/2013/11/detailed-review-of-ubuntu-touch-1404.html)

Hoping that will help you.