# Can ubuntu 16.04 work with touch screen computers?

Tags: touchscreen, compatibility

Can Ubuntu 16.04 work with touch screen computers?

The question '[Where I can find a summary of Ubuntu's current functionality on touch screen devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112762/where-i-can-find-a-summary-of-ubuntus-current-functionality-on-touch-screen-dev)' only had one answer that was related to Ubuntu touch, and didn't say anything about the standard Ubuntu (I couldn't leave a comment cos I only have 18 reputations).

Is Ubuntu compatible and usable with touch screens and 2-in-1 computers?

Comment: I am asking in general touch screen computers but i was also wondering if Ubuntu works on the 2 in 1 hybrids (I had in mind my Kogan atlus pro).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it can! According to my experience, Ubuntu 16.04 works perfectly with touch screen and 2 in 1 devices. I have [Lenovo X230 Tablet](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51mlomDVzKL._SY450_.jpg) and all of its features, including the Wacom stylus (and 3G module), work better under Ubuntu than under Windows. That is strange because the device is 'designed' for Windows.

Something more, within Ubuntu I was able to solve some little issues that I couldn't solve within Windows, for example: [How do I disable the touchpad when the lid is twisted or closed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980997/how-do-i-disable-the-touchpad-when-the-lid-is-twisted-or-closed)

Here is a demo how my stylus works with Gimp: [GIMP Pressure sensitivity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960261/gimp-pressure-sensitivity/960301#960301). Note that, I have not installed any additional (software) drivers to got the touch features to work.

Comment: Good so! - I am actually sitting here with a dual-boot, because - sorry - to me *buntu (kubuntu) is lousy on touchscreens. I'd love an extra tag, or subdir, where all the necessary information could be stored.
Firstly, I can't log on, because the virtual keyboard doesn't seem to reflect the keys that I press, so my password is 100% wrong. 
And when I'm in, there is no right click. And when I click to a text box, there is no screen keyboard popping up. And there is no way to write into a text box with the pen; like I can do with W10. 
Though I'd like to learn how to do all this!

Answer (score 2):

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 in a Lenovo yoga 13, this is a 2012 released touchscreen notebook. 
The touchscreen works well. However, it's not as sensitive as I could imagine. For example, it's not possible to draw. Not sure if this is because of Ubuntu or screen capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Almost a year ago my Windows 10 simply stopped working on my Chuwi Hi12, a cheap 2in1 PC. Before this happened I just heard about Linux but never used it. In order to keep using the device, I did a little research, and I concluded that Ubuntu was the best option for me. Today I am in love with Ubuntu, and also with the Linux community, but after a year, I am still not capable of making the touchscreen work, and I would love to have this feature on this device. I am not sure why it is not working, because in all of the forums, I have read that the touchscreen works without problem. I contacted the manufacturer (CHUWI), but they said me that they don't work with Linux.

Does anyone know how to make the touchscreen of the Chuwi Hi12 work with Ubuntu?